# Enter Cell Formula using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, quotes, formula

I have this simple formula in Cell A1

```
=10*Round(B1/10,0)
```

I know how to enter this in VBA, i simply write:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=10*Round(B1/10,0)"
```

Now, what if I don't know the cell whose number I want to round? In other words, i have an integer variable in my code, N, that can take on multiple values, and I want to round the number in row number N of column B.

How do I write this?
I tried:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=10*Round(B" & N & "  & "/10",0)"
```

But this doesn't work. Tried multiple layouts for the quotes but without success.

Can anyone let me know:

1. How to enter that simple formula? and more importantly
2. Provide some link/reference that would help me with entering other
   formulas in the future?

Thanks

Comment: `Range("A1").Formula = "=10*Round(B" & N & "/10,0)"`

Comment: You're rounding to the nearest 10? Equivalent formula is `=ROUND(B1,-1)`

Comment: Barry: Thank you very much, that's a very useful tip.

Excelllll: Also thanks a lot. Do you know where i can find the general rules for entering formulas like this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Barry and Excellll have clearly solved your specific question.  As to the more general, I've googled around, and was surprised not to find a good general tutorial on this.  Here's a [short post](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/04/16/worksheet-formulas-in-vba-part-i/) from Daily Dose of Excel.

I'd turn on the macro recorder, create some formuals, see what you get, and then google specific issues.  Finally, a good book, such as one of John Walkenbach's "Power Programming in VBA" titles should help.